# Defining an object type depending on field in another object

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm making an HTML table generator that takes a `columns` array and a `rows` array.

The goal is for the table generator to require certain types for each field in the objects of the `rows` array, depending on the "type" property for the corresponding key name in the `columns` object.

So for example, some example arguments for a "users" table where column 1 is the username and column 2 is a link to that user's profile:

```
 TableBody({
  columns: [
    { key: "username", label: "Username", type: "string" },
    { key: "userProfile", label: "Profile Page", type: "link" },
  ],
  rows: [
    {
      // username must be a string, according to the columns array
      username: "MangoMcgee",
      // userProfile must be a "link" type, according to the columns array
      userProfile: { text: "Mango's home page", href: "/user/mango-mcgee" },
    },
    {
      username: "PineapplePete",
      userProfile: {
        text: "Pineapple's home page",
        href: "/user/pineapple-pete",
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

I've defined my columns and rows like this:

```
type tableColumn<K> = {
  key: K;
  label: string;
  type: "string" | "link";
};

type tableRow<T extends tableColumn<string>[]> = {
  [key in T[number]["key"]]: "link" extends T[number]["type"]
     ? { text: string; href: string }
     : string;
};
```

Where I'm stuck: my definition of `tableRow<T>` is flawed.
My issue (I think) is that I was thinking `T[number]["type"]` would either be `"string"` or `"link"`, and I could then use the conditional of `"link" extends T[number]["type"]` to decide whether the property should be a `string` or a `{ text: string; href: string }`.

But I've realized that since I've defined `tableColumn<K>["type"]` to be the union `"string" | "link"`, it's always just that. It's not actually `"string"` *or* `"link"`, it's the union itself of `"string" | "link"`. So that conditional is always true.

I think I need to make the `type` property on `tableColumn` generic, instead of a union. But if `tableColumn` takes another generic type parameter, I'm not sure where I would actually pass in the type argument.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMCGBGAbCBhA9ogrgWwHYB4BpAPigF4oBvAWACgooBrCEALikIG46HEEJE7AM7AATgEtcAc270Y4COwBEIidKVQAPlCWJJjJbIC+suhAAeYNKODzIMBMgBKaAO74AKlAvAIuACZCDkioGDgEqpJSxADaALqkFDRyMcwgUJJQHjG4OPAQonExSmlKcXHKergG3ua+AUHZudj5hcWgkGU8DFAA-FQwPsJiUZxQABaiEABmw2pSUEbdDHOjdCZ0dAD0W1AAxmF4QbBTUFJoUTBoUPlQ0xD+UJHSQgA0ULABUKJux6fnl2A11u90eBywRxg41gthO0H8M0kDygmCEgPGaCE0CEsGw2JGLzoHWgHkcEAAQmh-CAAAo-MBCIi1eqBJ4EqTvLw+PysuAhdAQggkeKJKjdcHhITsPnIAXhIixOKyBg-VxS4LONyeRXGUy0A64ERZMmU6nkKBM7kNNnzTnMnlBGWhQUKkUACmSDAlR1e3VVb3W7FJIVNtPpjMInOIAEpyKRPd9fgA6abWACisD24zdbtVsbI8eW+0OhpT6cz2bd3tw+cLch6xcNGAgScQaCkubcMWrSbScWjyp6RgH3WHus2tAsVhsUAR01gmEQtmDyFDepXFKpIA94pL6piRcoTBYylRBVwuIgSnefHygh0AFUsaIL3jr3ZFDpnlINEZffWBjSU9nzpNBpnEZB31vARlFA8DkCgGlYCkK93mJSp9F-f8GDibDEzVdgDwAhMGx2D8hD2CQwFsVxPmAR1xnER1gWgVNRGwGFfEePRmA+HQqhqYkiwYM8X0vZQAFlPnOCS9hQ1DhJRECfngz8j18OpJOktAAHIggxPEoDAZDUImKZZh0LZRK2DjpDQABabA5IgK9Fjwhg-0PRTRNfT8lBpJFYDAMBkBpCBfGvbzlLAiC1MUhgNOAWDAuC5A9ImNBDOMlDIoAhtJhmZQrOfLYwBSkKIHsyAIvcodas8uRcPWAcgA)

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoAl8N) what you are looking for?

Comment: @caTS yes indeed, that's incredible!!

Comment: @caTS any idea why I get type errors when defining rows and columns _before_ calling TableBody? [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WY3YzN)

Comment: Yeah, [use `as const`](https://tsplay.dev/Nnb4kN) with the arrays. I also changed the definitions to accept readonly things to make this work. One downside is that the error doesn't occur where you define the rows, but where you try to use it, and the error given is a little cryptic. I'll write an answer if this works for you.

Comment: Yeah that looks good! Btw seems like we only have to use `as const` on `columns` [https://tsplay.dev/WkkjpW]. Which is perfect, because the actual table data will probably be coming from somewhere else, not just typed literally into the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, let's map some of the "types" to the types we'll be using for the result:

```
type ColTypes = {
  string: string;
  link: {
    text: string;
    href: string;
  };
};
```

Then we'll create a type to make another type, given the columns:

```
type TypeFromCols<
  Cols extends readonly { key: string; label: string; type: "string" | "link" }[]
> = {
  [K in Cols[number]["key"]]: ColTypes[Extract<
    Cols[number],
    { key: K }
  >["type"]];
};
```

Mapping over each key, we extract the column from the array and then get the corresponding type. The definition for `TableBody` now looks like:

```
type ColArgs = {
  key: string;
  label: string;
  type: "string" | "link";
};

const TableBody = <Cols extends readonly ColArgs[]>(body: {
  columns: Narrow<Cols>;
  rows: readonly TypeFromCols<Cols>[];
}) => { /* ... */ };
```

You'll notice another type, `Narrow`, and this is just to make TypeScript infer the argument as a giant object literal (if it was passed directly):

```
type Narrow<T> =
  | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
  | Extract<
      T,
      number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []
    >
  | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });
```

This has no effect on the result and is just a QoL thing so you don't need `as const` when using `TableBody({ columns: { ... } as const, ... })`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwCrggZygXigbwFBRRrABOAlgHYDmAXEaZVQNwFQKUDWd+hhwEAD2B1i5ai15QAFiQgAzEQ3GsAvizV48oSFBSQAYiTgBbeAjQAeVmYyD+FACYZZAQwdwKCELigcIIRTFmNhcAIwgEQMYmKG0IOgAiUUYEqAAfKAT2Cg5UlQBtAF08AD4sXFZ8gGkoSlhENHyKAFdjcJJC-IS-EATCwrozPXR8gFEhEhcAY2ArSRsm1vbCgBpWQhxffzoalVYSrri+wvUWLVQoADkXEiMAdwskMsxWDIAKJCg7CEcMSjkICQoABVKAAfhBUDoFAgADdAQBKV5Qcakaazda8JBrSSEFptQHpehBImhOCICAuCikshUSjAIloEBtRBEloIBBE5qOeSUCAOIlFTElZFvfJIQpfIQ-JxQfJFSUQopQnzVWrUnpwOS6AZXG73R7VQplFQIs5xeoIACCJCoGGwPC2AWJ0VYCDCESiyj4qESyWoqQyWU4CVOmimHmIujCCAgACE4A5vNgLDYpfZZa53J5vGYbXaiiU3mSk9xWBGEK0KGg6NdbnAHjYShIoPca63KdmvLpUIYTDZUw0Dic8KasGUcBo8EgY-HEyA3o6K1X2-lMZseolmmhARQXMYIAkViFwpFMsCdyQ9wej7FfZl-VQ8jjeBvtplt4CAApGORkWO3u6p6JD+Wr-tAX4uFQh7HnEiTZLkUAqC+qysG2dBrpIAD0WFQHAHDrpihCfle+7xJkACyVJUHAFFTNBMFEVAJGgX+sbcLEdiJFR1BwAA5BgUgmNAYBQTB0iyAomRYSRWHGNRcAALTGPRECHkhL6EMhhG4sxl7XuRCRfnyLhgGAsZfhA-BHkxLG-uBZa6XwXGZMZMKmeZEACdIwlQKJ0E2U5EnyIkMmXlhYAmWZsaKZA1mabw2mSNpmI4V89YkGg65Ja+em7mRdAAIwAEwAMwACwAKwAGzHnZYHsT4-BCIkxjeGA9kAceMghdJUwuEgADKeQaeueWkQeiT9UNt71Wx5GbM1whQOVxXdZJoXTcNSGjZImwkQZU0DdtOUbONrEOU1LkJG1fmdeJPVSQkWFbSNOWoaaZwRtWDLLsY1blJhPibh++lkYBHpngkF75TesH3kkShPrtwPvgkc3gRDwGufdUCQQF8OQPBIajZKLgYN9xBfZGDJtoDrBpfhrCOsRYOTZRCl0QxgW8BjjWLddPE0d5QkHn5Ym3o9oWyfJvHKap6k5TlLPjYdrlRZ5lnxZifMLUxS0gRrsYi75-mMbpUvSbJkXudFECxVZ5uJS+KWEGlgJGJlUBvGQ2ogHAzQdsYcDwlALgcnh2rAFI6DQHIRjGLEUhkBg+ouCAsEx9S0fQB7cBAqeDZQHc-6cuEUA0TCSIbMrqsFVAJUVTVdWXhd-OcS1mS3R1DUPRtfXHW9L77WzhmvS3373RxBsrWtwVPS9g87bXB31wkr0oyPk+99P13d-dkv989G8qKTYcUzTZwzqEsYJkmi4M7hwxQHxb7Oo+MRAZ6LriHeRM-8EAohQ+K1AwBQOADJyZoFpHuG+0BgBwD-tAPidYDR5ltI0Y0fEAB05ZEArhfG2NYn08BAA)